Can I do multiple processes using Threading in python to achieve a "Idle game" kind of code?
So I kind of want to create an idle game, but I can't figure out how to get the system of "Money per second" to work.
The idea is to have a main function that takes input from the user and another function that gives you money per second.
I tried using the Python threading module to achieve results in a seperate code, but unfortunatly it did not work as expected.
import time
import threading

def testing_main():
  print("Wait for meeee")
  wait = input()
  if wait == "True":
    print("wait")

def testing_side():
  print("Hi")

while True:
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=testing_main)
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=testing_side)
  if t1.is_alive() == False:
    t1.start()
    print("Thread is alive")
  t2.start()
  t2.join()

The idea is to have the side program running in the background while the main program waits for user input to do something.

Can you explain your requirement clearly? Try sample input and output.

Loop in the thread instead. Don't create a ton of threads in the loop. If you want testing_side to do some background task, you would presumably want to do something like use a while True (maybe have it check a threading.Event to know when to terminate) in the side thread, put a time.sleep(1) in the loop, and then also have the loop increment a money counter in some thread-safe way.

Thanks! Really helped a lot
